# istringstream не проходит всю строку

Tags: c++

Суть алгоритма: `std::istringstream` (как я понимаю) сам автоматически отсекает пробелы, оставляя число. Это число заносится в массив. Суть в том, что `istringstream` считывает число 30, и дальше считывание не идет, просто увеличивается индекс.

Код:

```
int *timeLine = new int();

std::string sLine = "";
std::string tLine = "";
std::string lastZero = "";
int indexNumber = 0;
std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);

while (sLine != "0 0 0")
    {
        int temp = 1;
        getline(infile, sLine);

        std::istringstream stream (sLine);

        lastZero = sLine[sLine.length() - 2];
        lastZero += sLine[sLine.length() - 1];

        std::istringstream tStream (tLine);

        if ((sLine != "0 0 0") && lastZero == " 0") {

            tLine = tLine + " " + sLine;
            std::cout << tLine << "\n";

            while (temp != 0) {

                tStream >> temp;

                if (temp != 0) {
                    timeLine[indexNumber] = temp;
                    indexNumber++;
                }
            }

        } else {

            tLine = tLine + " " + sLine;
            std::cout << tLine << "\n";
        }

    }
```

Вид текста в файле:

```
 19  20
30
  25 35 0
0 0 0
```

Результат сложения строки во время чтения файла:
19 20 30 25 35 0

0 - конец строки. Потом сам алгоритм добавления каждого числа в массив.

**Обновление**

`timeLine` - динамический массив. Есть строка, которая заканчивается нулем. Но бывают варианты, когда строка (в файле) разбита на подстроки, как показано "Вид текста в файле". С этой белеберды я создаю одну цельную строчку (вместе с нулем), показано на "Результат сложения". Теперь прохожусь стрингстримом и считываю числа в массив. Но стрингстрим почему-то останавливается на числе 30 и дальше числа не считывает, и они, естественно, не попадают в массив. Приложение тупо висит, типа что-то там себе считывает.

Вот и не могу понять, почему так происходит. Стрингстрим сам удаляет пробелы. Пробелов между числами может быть несколько. Но на работу не влияет.

Comment: А Вы словами может описать, что хотите получить? А то из Вашего кода ничего не понятно. И почему у timeLine индексы?

Comment: Я нашел свою ошибку. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Стрингстрим не удаляет пробелы. Просто код, который читает с него число `tStream >> temp;` автоматом пропускает пробелы, потом читает само число до первого символа, который не является числом. Этим символом оказывается пробел или перевод строки:)

А ошибка Ваша скорее всего в том, что timeLine - динамический массив маленького размера. Используйте std::vector, если уже пишете `c++11`.

Comment: @iSerg, судя по приведенному коду, после каждого 

    timeLine[indexNumber] = temp;

Вам нужно написать не только

    indexNumber++;

но и увеличивать область памяти, на которую указывает `timeLine`, не забывая переписать в нее старое содержимое `timeLine[]`.

Ничего сложного здесь нет (особенно если вместо `new/delete` сразу использовать `realloc`), но IMHO пока Вам лучше последовать совету @KoVadim и использовать `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Я просто передвинул строчку std::istringstream tStream (tLine); под строчку tLine = tLine + " " + sLine;. Пока все работает.

Comment: @iSerg, речь идет о

    int *timeLine = new int();

Вы отводите память **ровно под одно** число. Все следующие пишутся в память, которую Вы **не выделяли**. 

Так что, "пока все работает" -- это до тех пор, пока данных мало. 

Исправьте.

Comment: Все пошло так как Вы и говорили =). При 3-4-х входящих числах в массив еще нормально было, но при 5-ти и более пошла кракозябра. Воспользовался Вашим с @KoVadim советами и использовал вектор. Теперь все работает отлично. Спасибо.

Comment: @iSerg, вообще-то всегда надо проверять, успешно ли прочли число в таких местах, как:

       tStream >> temp;

Ведь если попадется символ, отличный от пробела (табуляции, ньюлайна ...) или цифры, то на нем этот Ваш цикл

    while (temp != 0) {
        ...

станет бесконечным.

Надо проверять, и если чтение неудачно, то в зависимости от задачи ... (или обругаться и все закончить, или читать новую строку и работать уже с ней, или ... сами придумайте).

Comment: @iSerg, получил Ваш (уже удаленный Вами же) комментарий с данными, на которых программа циклится и повнимательней посмотрел код.


Циклится программа, безусловно, во вншнем 

     while (sLine != "0 0 0") {
        ...

поскольку Вы не проверяете

           getline(infile, sLine);

на конец файла. Строка `sLine` в этом случае будет пустой (**но так EOF определять нельзя!!!**) и .... см. свой код и думайте.

IMHO, лучше писать так:

      string sLine;
      while (getline(infile, sLine)) {
        ... анализ введеной строки в соответствии с заданием
           (которое мы не знаем)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@iSerg](/users/16314/iserg)](/users/16314/iserg):
Мой Вам совет.

Рекомендация №1
Перепишите код! Разбейте задачу, решаемую вашей процедурой, на несколько более мелких подзадач и для каждой подзадачи напишите по процедуре. А в последствии при более-менее понятном коде Вам будет проще сделать оптимизацию, если о ней Вам намекнет Ваш профайлер.

Дело в том, что Вы не можете разобраться в Вашем коде из-за того, что в нем решается более чем одна задача! Декомпозируйте, назначайте подцели и достигайте подцели.

Рекомендация №2
Пишите формируемый результат в std::stringstream, а при возврате результата вызовете его rdbuf() для записи в любой из потомков std::ostream.